# Why am i getting [object object ] after insert a JSON Object to mssql table (Node.js)

Tags: sql, node.js, azure

i am building an API and i am trying to insert Json obj to my Azure sql db after i made a post request. I get this result:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTcLz.jpg)

my InsertUser.sql :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[insertUser]  
(  

    @username varchar(50),  
    @email nvarchar(max),  
    @password nvarchar(max),
    @hobbies nvarchar(max)   
    )  
    AS  
    BEGIN  
    insert into users (username,email,password,hobbies) values( @username, @email, @password,@hobbies)  
    END
```

my CreateUserTable.sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Users.users', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Users.users
GO
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE users
(
    username [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- primary key column
    email [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    password [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    hobbies [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL 
    -- specify more columns here
);
GO
```

my route user.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const { poolPromise } = require('../../config/db')  
const sql = require('mssql')  
const bcrypt = require ('bcryptjs');
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator')


//@route POST/api/users 
//@desc Insert new user
//@access Public

router.post('/',[
    check('username', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please include a valid e-mail').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please enter a password with 8 or more characters').isLength({min:8}).isAlpha(),
    check('hobbies', 'hobbies required').not().isEmpty(),
    ],
     async (req,res)=>  {  
    try{
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const {username,password,email,hobbies} = req.body;

          //Password bcrypt

        const salt= await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        cryptpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,salt);

        //insert to DB
        const pool = await poolPromise  
        const result = await pool.request()
        .input("username",sql.VarChar(50), username)
        .input("email", sql.VarChar(50),email)
        .input("password",sql.VarChar(50),cryptpassword)
        .input("hobbies", sql.NVarChar('max'),hobbies)
        .execute("InsertUser").then(function (recordSet){
        res.status(200).json({ status: "Success" })  
        })  

    }

    catch(error){
            console.error(error.message)
            res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }


});
module.exports = router;
```

in postman i am trying:

```
{
    "username":"davidzz12z1",
    "email":"davidzal1992@gmail.com",
    "password":"asdasdadadsadsad",
    "hobbies":[
        {"first": "football"},
        {"second": "baskteball"}
            ]

}
```

its seems that i should define my procedure to get some json file but i didnt find how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the content of hobbies property:

from

```
[
        {"first": "football"},
        {"second": "baskteball"}
            ]
```

to:

```
"[\n        {\"first\": \"football\"},\n        {\"second\": \"baskteball\"}\n            ]"
```

as another option, just wrap the content with a single quote:

```
'[
            {"first": "football"},
            {"second": "baskteball"}
                ]'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#import-json-data-into-sql-server-tables

Comment: its works, but its looks  like a little strange way to do that, because after every user post request i have to take his inputs and change the hobbies to this new syntax? there is no another way?

Comment: According to the official documentation, you can also add a single quote at the beginning and at the end. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#import-json-data-into-sql-server-tables